# Log response body apache with the client IP

Tags: apache, httpresponse, mod-security, audit-logging

I need to log the server response body along with the client which requested it.

- Tried `mod_dumpio` which logs the response body but it doesn't reveal
  the client IP so I am not able to map the request and response.
- The other option was audit log which seemed the exact tool I needed,
  but    [it](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#SecAuditLogParts) doesn't support logging actual response body as
  yet.

Could anyone please suggest me an appropriate solution?